# Scala mutable MultiMap addBinding and insert order preservation

Tags: scala

It appears that MultiMap's addBinding does not preserve the insertion order of values binded to a same key, as the underlying mechanism it uses is a HashSet. What may be an idiomatic way to preserve insertion order with a MultiMap?

Answer (score 6):

Based on [`MultiMap`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.scala) where the implementation states:

```
/** Creates a new set.
*
*  Classes that use this trait as a mixin can override this method
*  to have the desired implementation of sets assigned to new keys.
*  By default this is `HashSet`.
*
*  @return An empty set of values of type `B`.
*/
protected def makeSet: Set[B] = new HashSet[B]
```

You can simply define:

```
trait OrderedMultimap[A, B] extends MultiMap[A, B] {
    override def makeSet: Set[B] = new LinkedHashSet[B]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't additional methods need to be overridden too? checking out the source code... thanks! :)

Comment: No, the implementation requires a ``Set``, whatever the implementation is

Answer (score 0):

One way would probably be to fall back to a regular Map (not MultiMap), using a collection for the value type, whereas that collection would be a collection type where order can be enforced (i.e. not a Set). As I understand, to preserve order of insertion in the wider sense that allows element repetition, the natural Scala collection to use would be a Seq implementation (e.g. Vector, or Queue, depending on the access patterns).